# React dataTable data not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable

I'm using react-datatable-component and when I click the row icon to remove an object from my array, I would like that the item I just removed from the array would also be removed from the table.

This is my 'columns':

```
columns_itens = [
        {
            name: 'Descricao',
            selector: 'descricao_material',
            sortable: true,
        },
        {
        ignoreRowClick: true,
        allowOverflow: true,
        cell: row => 
                <div>
                    <Icon
                        title="Adicionar ao carrinho"  
                        onClick={this.addHandler.bind(this,row)}
                        className="icone fa fa-cart-plus">
                    </Icon>
                </div>
        }
    ]
```

That's how I'm handling the add Icon:

```
addHandler(item) {
        console.log(item)
        let itens_table = this.state.itens;
        let x = 0;
        itens_table.map(i => {
            if(i.id == item.id)
                itens_table.splice(x, 1);
            x++;
        })
        this.setState({itens: itens_table}, ()=>console.log(this.state.itens));
    }
```

This is how I'm rendering the table:

```
render() {  
        return (
             <div className="containerItens">
                   <div className="dataTable">
                      <DataTable
                      title="Solicitações"
                      columns={this.columns_itens}
                      data={this.state.itens}
                      striped
                      defaultSortField
                      pagination
                      />
                   </div>
             </div>
         );
```